# Override iTunes "media" keys (play, pause, etc) for Spotify?

Tags: itunes, keyboard, spotify

Is it possible to set Spotify as the default program when the "media" keys (play, pause, previous, next, etc) are pressed on the Mac keyboard?

For the most part when Spotify is open, the "media" keys work fine. But every once and a while iTunes will pop up when you hit them. It'd be a lot nicer if you could just specify that Spotify is the default program when these keys are triggered, as oppose to iTunes.

If it matters, I'm using Mountain Lion.

Comment: A similar question at Super User: [What can I do to stop the Play / Pause button from opening iTunes?](http://superuser.com/questions/31925/what-can-i-do-to-stop-the-play-pause-button-from-opening-itunes)

Comment: I think the key feature that is being looked for here is for Spotify to be opened when one of the media keys is presses.

Comment: Allow the media keys to work for multiple apps and websites with Beardedspice: http://beardedspice.github.io/

Comment: Two things with BeardedSpice (AKA, BS)
1) After you go in an uncheck all other apps, except Spotify, you have to close and reopen it
2) Spotify must be already running for the Play/Pause button to work (sadpepe)

BS will not work if the Spotify app is not already running (i.e. it will not launch it, like MacOS did natively for Apple Music/iTunes). BS definitely doesn't give the same functionality, but it is "good enough" as long as I always leave Spotify open (yes, BS has Accessibility permissions)

FYI - on Ventura 13.4 here you need BS, as Mac Media Key Forwarder is incompatible.

Answer (score 87):

The software *[Mac Media Key Forwarder](https://github.com/quentinlesceller/macmediakeyforwarder)* provides a user-friendly approach to prioritizing Spotify for your media keys. It runs in the background and gives you a few simple settings in the Mac menu bar. It just works.

[image: Mac Media Key Forwarder menu options]

**Download and installation**

It can be downloaded and installed directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/quentinlesceller/macmediakeyforwarder), or by using e.g. Homebrew:

```
brew install macmediakeyforwarder
```

**Notes**

- It is compatible with macOS Ventura.
- Ensure the application is given [sufficient privileges](https://support.apple.com/en-my/guide/mac-help/mh43185/mac) in *Security & Privacy* in the *System Preferences*.
- I am not affiliated with the developer(s), I am just a satisfied user.

---

**Update 2023-08-28 - Use *Mac Media Key Forwarder* as the alternative app *Beardedspice* is no longer being updated**

As there are [reports](https://github.com/milgra/macmediakeyforwarder/issues/81#issuecomment-539969280) of *Beardedspice* not working for some users, and the developer no longer updating the app, it is recommended to use *[Mac Media Key Forwarder](https://github.com/quentinlesceller/macmediakeyforwarder)*. *[Mac Media Key Forwarder](https://github.com/quentinlesceller/macmediakeyforwarder)* is a fork of the original and it is receiving updates. The fork is recommended by the original author.

Nevertheless, *[Beardedspice](http://beardedspice.github.io)* will still work fine for most people running on e.g. MacOS *High Sierra*, *Mojave*, *Catalina*, *Big Sur*, *Monterey* or *Ventura* so it remains an alternative.

[image: Beardedspice running in the background to handle media keys.]

**Download and installation**

It can be downloaded and installed directly from [the *Beardedspice* homepage](http://beardedspice.github.io), or by using e.g. Homebrew:

```
brew install beardedspice
```

**Notes**

- Beardedspice supports controlling a vast amount of media players. Simply disable any unwanted players, while keeping Spotify enabled.

Comment: I couldn't get `macmediakeyforwarder` to work, but found a similar project called `beardedspice` which seems to have more support: https://github.com/beardedspice/beardedspice

Comment: @Alan It still works flawlessly, but systems differ. In case an update is needed, then the latest version can always be found at *[Mac Media Key Forwarder - versions](http://milgra.com/downloads/mmkf/)*. Indeed, your linked project will also address the issue and is beneficial if one wants further customization options. Thanks for referencing it.

Comment: Tried the latest version and still couldn't get it working for me. Seems like the milgra is aware of the issue but doesn't know how to resolve it: https://github.com/milgra/macmediakeyforwarder/issues/81#issuecomment-539969280 -- tried beardedspice and worked like a charm

Comment: The feedback is much appreciated. I have altered the solution description to include these issue reports and the alternative software that can be used to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: I couldn't find/add my own player to the list :/

Comment: @Dr.jacky Have a look at the [supported apps and sites](http://beardedspice.github.io#about) for BeardedSpice, and how to add new ones.

Comment: does this work on big sur?

Comment: @JohnD *Mac Media Key Forwarder* should work on macOS Big Sur (as long as it is given sufficient privileges). I did however update the main recommendation to be *Beardedspice*, due to *Mac Media Key Forwarder* no longer being maintained by the developer.

Comment: i just tried beardedspice and it seems to have broken my pause/play key. Now it no longer responds ti inout even after uninstalling it :(

Comment: BeardedSpice is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/beardedspice/beardedspice/issues/899) but [Beardie](https://github.com/Stillness-2/beardie) has forked and is much improved

Comment: Neither BeardedSpice or Beardie are opening Spotify when I press play. I'm on Monterey 12.0.1

Comment: Just to rule the easy things out. Is the Spotify checkbox activated in the Media Controllers list?

Comment: BeardedSpice with the config in this post, didn't make Spotify pop up from pressing play, for me, but it did stop iTunes from popping up.  However, it made play/pause consistently take a full second to register which was really annoying.  Had to uninstall it then restart the computer to get back to prior state.  This was on BigSur

Comment: I've just tested both and Mac Media Key was the only one that truly allowed me to prioritize Spotify above all other apps. This release works with macOS Monterey https://github.com/quentinlesceller/macmediakeyforwarder/releases

Comment: Mac Media Key Forwarder is not working anymore on MacOS Monterey 12.5.1; I used it for a couple of years, until it simply stopped working. I had to uninstall it.

Comment: @ReinierGarcia *Mac Media Key Forwarder* still works in my system running 12.5.1. I recommend checking the app's access in Security & Privacy - although you have probably done so already.

Comment: Does it use Spotify exclusively or still maintain the core functionality of play/pause the last active media app? I.e. switching between YouTube, Spotify or VLC.

Comment: You are able to select all applications / media controllers (Spotify, Youtube, VLC, …) you want the software to track. Last active is then the method of selecting between them.

As a sidenote, it might be beneficial to give Beardie (https://github.com/Stillness-2/beardie) a try rather than Beardedspice as the former is actively maintained.

Comment: Tried BeardedSpice: It stopped Apple Music from opening, but it wouldn't open Spotify instead. Alright - I guess it kinda helped. Annoying to install an entirely separate app to stop that. Noticed it wasn't maintained and tried the fork, Beardie. Also didn't solve it. Uninstalled both. Now my Play/Pause button does not work at all. Great. Not sure which app caused it. Ugh.

Comment: @TJBiddle Sorry to hear that. *Mac Media Key Forwarder* continues to run well on MacOS Ventura. Did you give this a try?

Comment: Similarly to TJBiddle, not only installing BeaderdSpice wouldn't open Spotify, it'd keep on crashing Spotify after a few seconds of playing something. Argh.

Answer (score 41):

I find this problem happens for me inconsistently, so I use this fairly destructive approach when it happens:

1. Open up "Activity Monitor", which can be found easily using Spotlight
2. Select either "CPU" or "Memory" from the pills at the top of the dialog
3. In the search box, top right, type: `itunes`
4. "ituneshelper" is what you're looking for. Find it, click on it, then select "Force kill"
5. Accept the confirmation

Spotify also has a helper running. My guess is that it depends which one loads first.

---

### Permanent solution

Per comment below – you can simply remove it from your login items:

1. Search for 'Login Items' in System Preferences
2. Select itunes helper
3. Click [-] button
4. Restart your mac

Comment: Instead of killing it every time, you could disable it in your login items, thanks though, was driving me nuts

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: or "killall iTunesHelper" from the shell ?

Comment: @geermc4's answer is the correct long-term solution. It'll stop iTunes from launching whenever your computer restarts.

If you never restart your computer, follow jakeisonline's answer.

Comment: This worked for me: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/ituneshelper-keeps-appearing-in-login-items.1429456/#post-17114130
for posterity ... 
The iTuneshelper.app is part of the iTunes package. To diable the iTuneshelper.app you have to view the contents of the iTunes.app by Option clicking, or right clicking, and choosing "Show Package Contents". The iTuneshelper.app is located in the MacOS folder.

Rename iTuneshelper.app to iTuneshelper-disable.app and this will prevent it from launching and being added to Login Items."

Comment: This didn't work for me in macOS 10.13.2 (17C205)

Comment: Doesn't work in 10.13.5 either, looks like this is no longer a valid solution ):

Comment: Doesn't work in 10.14 either.

Comment: Not 10.15 either

Comment: "Not 10.15 either "in october 9th 2018? Mojave is version 10.14. There is no OSX 10.15 yet. Are you from the future?

Comment: I can confirm that this works even in 2019, on an Apple Mac Mini. Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering why it's the highest votes answer if it's doesn't work for anyone?! (for me too). Consider voting "-1" in this case. That's exactly the way to bring attention to the question.

Comment: Have no iTunes helper in Login Items.

Answer (score 24):

Lifehacker ran an article about this very problem a while back for Snow Leopard. http://lifehacker.com/5531707/free-your-macs-media-keys-from-itunes-grasp

> The tricks we used before were far less than ideal, requiring you to start up QuickTime in the background, or do some serious hacking to system files within iTunes.app. NoMitsu has created a one-click installer that patches the remote control daemon, the app responsible for managing the media keys. Just download the patch and double-click on it. After entering your password, your media keys will be free from iTunes' grasp.

I presume you have already tried this.  As I recall the media keys will control the last program that was active so if Spotify was the last media app you had open (and is currently open) then the media keys will control that.   Hope this helps you out.

Comment: "As I recall the media keys will control the last program that was active so if Spotify was the last media app you had open (and is currently open) then the media keys will control that. Hope this helps you out."

No. That's now how it works. Tested it on 10.13.2 and it doesn't work like that. It keeps on opening iTunes.

Comment: The link to the download of that mmix.app by NoMitsu is broken and there doesn't seem to be any non-suspicious looking source for it. Also The link you provide goes to an older lifehacker article, that references [the article your are quoting from](https://lifehacker.com/free-your-macs-media-keys-from-itunes-no-manual-hackin-5651055).

Answer (score 19):

I'v had this problem for years and in my case it goes beyond iTunes. When working in Keynote or another application that "claims" the media keys, controlling Spotify (or other music players) won't work.

But now I've finally solved it!

Quite a long process but here goes.

Binding Media keys to one Media player, and that player only:

- Go to system preferences > Keyboard > and select "Use all F1, F2, etc keys as standard function keys". (this will disable all quick controls like brightness, and volume)
  (To enable those again:)
- Download "Karabiner"
- Choose "Change F1..F19 Key & Function key..." > "Change F1..F19 Key" > "F1..F12 to Functional Key"
- Enable all but "F7, F8, F9 to music Controls" (unless you'd like to map any other keys to features of your choice) (now the brightness etc. should be working again)
- Download and install FastScripts
- Open Automator and create a new Service
- Change "service receives selected:" [text] to [no input]
- Add the "run apple script" action to the main screen
- Enter and save the following three apple scripts (for Spotify, but I'm sure this works with some other media players to) to the folder [your user]/Library/Scripts:

---

```
try
tell application "Spotify"
    playpause
end tell
end try
return
```

---

```
try
tell application "Spotify"
    previous track
end tell
end try
return
```

---

```
try
tell application "Spotify"
    next track
end tell
end try
return
```

- And finally in In FastScripts, go to "Script Shortcuts" and set F7, F8, and F9 as shortcuts for your scripts!

Easy as that! =)

EDIT: Karabiner does not yet work with Sierra, but a pre-release called "Karabiner Elements" does the trick. In that case, skip the first 4 steps in the above list and instead:

- Install Karabiner Elements
- Select Function keys and map f7>f7, f8>f8, f9>f9
  (then continue from the list above by installing Fastscripts.)

Comment: Give this guy a medal.

Comment: Then you might as well use the spotify native shortcuts. Media keys are special keycodes... they are not function keys. That they occupy the same space on your keyboard is incidental, and does not solve my problem. The question here is well-asked and only a answer that addresses the question asked will solve my issue. For instance, my Bluetooth headset sends through the media keys as part of their controls, and this hack does not help me. Nor will it help me if I had some non-standard keyboard.

Comment: How do you mean?

The native shortcuts only work when you're using Spotify (and when you've switched to another application that does not claim the media keys for itself), right? Switching to keynote for example breaks Spotifys "bind" on media keys and prevents you from controlling Spotify.

I read your question again, and in my understanding I had the exact same problem as you. This solution solved it for me, so maybe try it again?

Comment: Worked for me, but I was encountering a bit of lag. I'm not sure if the bottleneck is the service or Fastscripts. I noticed that executing other scripts have a bit of lag as well, so that's where I'm leaning towards.

Answer (score 8):

After looking around for a while I finally found https://github.com/zsszatmari/MagicKeys

It is not specific to Spotify but will let you select any application to launch when a media key is pressed.

There are only 2 small issues I see with it (and one is also an issue with the default iTunes behavior).

1. It opens the application with any of the 3 media buttons. While this is what the original question requested, it is not the default behavior for iTunes. iTunes only opens when you press the play/pause button (not the back/forward buttons). Ideally this would be an option that the user could select.
2. It does not start the media playing after the application is launched. The same thing is also true with iTunes by default but it would be nice if you just had to press play once to open Spotify and start playing music rather than to press the key, wait for the app to start and then press the key again.

Comment: This is it. This is the best answer.
Download Magic Keys from: https://github.com/zsszatmari/MagicKeys/releases and use these settings: http://treasurebox-gear.s3.amazonaws.com/magickeys.png

Comment: This worked for me! I found/downloaded it from here: http://www.gearmusicplayer.com/extras.html

Comment: Must reboot for this to work. Far and a way the best solution of all.

Answer (score 7):

Settings>User & Groups>Login Items

- remove Itunes helper
- Add Spotify (check hide)

Restart your computer. It will always play Spotify since it's open in the background and not itunes.

[image]

Comment: Wasn't able to make this solution work on the newer M1 Macs.

Answer (score 5):

Adding on to what @sjg said, you could have Spotify opened at startup (presuming that you don't care for iTunes to open at startup) so that you can have the media keys work with Spotify right from login. Again, this is only a workaround and not really a full solution, but if you want it to be opened at startup, go to Spotify>Preferences and scroll down to "Open Spotify automatically after you login to the computer" and select Open automatically.

Answer (score 5):

You can go to your Applications library and manually delete iTunes.app in the terminal using:

`sudo rm -rf /Applications/iTunes.app`

Won't automatically make Spotify your default media player but iTunes will no longer exist on your computer.

Comment: The question is not how to remove iTunes, but how to change keyboard behavior. Removing an app provided with the OS is a dangerous way to solve the play button sporadically opening iTunes.

Comment: Still, there's something nice about this brutal answer.

Comment: I can confirm that this works in Mojave and to be iTunes-free is amazing.

Comment: bit heavy handed, but sure.  another alternative is to remove the execution bit: `sudo chmod -x /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes`

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in the comment by Beau Smith, the app [BeardedSpice](http://beardedspice.github.io/) do an amazing job! Not only for Spotify but also for a lot of other services (Netflix, Youtube, SoundCloud, etc.)

---

> BeardedSpice is a menubar application for Mac OSX that allows you to control web based media players and some native apps with the media keys found on Mac keyboards. It is an extensible application that works with Chrome (Canary, Yandex, Chromium) and Safari, and can control any tab with an applicable media player.

Answer (score 4):

Is better going to User (**Settings ->Users and Groups**) and then click on **"Startup items" and disable ituneshelper**. By this way you don't need to kill the process every time you switch on the device.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

a solution that worked for me for **Mojave** was to remove the execution bit from iTunes:

`sudo chmod -x /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes`

and optionally add the media player in question under

`Preferences -> Security & privacy -> Accessibility`

Comment: I was unable to do this until I had disabled `System Integrity Protection (CIP)` - `csrutil disable` during recovery mode.

Comment: Correct, i have that disabled a long time ago.  As a result, I can't tell what works with/without it :}

Comment: This worked for me, I didn't even needed the terminal part. Just enabled Deezer to control my computer... Thanks!

Comment: Ha, they very specifically made a change that breaks this. On Catalina, you now have the Music app which, strangely, lives in `System`, but `Unable to change file mode on /System/Applications/Music.app/Contents/MacOS/Music: Operation not permitted` _even with sudo_. /sigh

Comment: YMMV, on catalina Music.app is way less aggresive in stealing the media keys (when it's not running) to the point that i am not looking for ways to disable it. If i have a media player running, the media keys just work.  If nothing is running, only then Music.app starts.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how this should work:

1. Pressing a media key on your keyboard should send a message to the currently-active application, if it's one that supports media keys
2. If not, the most recently-active media-key-supporting application should be sent the message
3. If no application is available, open the default media-key-supporting application (e.g. iTunes, but configurable)
4. Each media-key-supporting application should have an opt-out in its preferences

It doesn't seem that difficult to me, yet this is one of those small usability flaws of OSX that sits on a pile of things that just serves to make the overall experience sub-par.

Answer (score 3):

I've created an easier implementation of [Per's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249075/109123) with [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/).

1. Download BetterTouchTool (it has a 45 day free trial, afterwards its a one time purchase of $9).
2. Create a keyboard shortcut, bound to the Play/Pause key.
3. *Optional: if you wish to open Spotify when its closed, add the following action (Apple Script (blocking)):*

[image: Open Spotify]

```
tell application "Spotify"
    if it is not running then launch
    set frontmost to true
    activate
end tell
```

4. Add an Apple Script (async in background) action:
   [image: Pause/Play Spotify]

```
using terms from application "Spotify"
    if player state of application "Spotify" is paused then
        tell application "Spotify" to play
    else
        tell application "Spotify" to pause
    end if
end using terms from
```

Comment: This is handy, I already use BTT for my trackpad and window snapping, so it tacks on well. I also notice that this makes my next/previous keys to work with spotify as well.

Answer (score 3):

A quick update from March 2023, for anyone else who stumbled upon this post:

At time of typing, it looks like there hasn't been a new release of [Beardedspice](https://github.com/beardedspice/beardedspice) since June 2017.

Meanwhile, Milgra, the original author of MacMediaKeyForwarder, [now recommends](https://github.com/milgra/macmediakeyforwarder) using the Quentinlesceller fork of his project (latest release April 2022): [MacMediaKeyForwarded (fork)](https://github.com/quentinlesceller/macmediakeyforwarder).

I can confirm that MacMediaKeyForwarder fork (3.1.1) works flawlessly with Spotify in Monterey 12.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

As of October 7, 2023, this is the **easiest and working solution** I have seen:

1. Install [noTunes](https://github.com/tombonez/noTunes)
2. Open the noTunes application and [add it to Login Items](https://github.com/tombonez/noTunes#ventura-and-later)
3. That's it!
4. (Optional) Open any application you want [in replacement of iTunes/Music](https://github.com/tombonez/noTunes#set-replacement-for-itunes--apple-music) when you press the **Play** button

Comment: Works great. App is small and lean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bundle that works as a good solution:

https://github.com/rpendleton/spotify-rcd

Comment: Why do you feel it's a good solution? What are the advantages (/disadvantages) compared with the other solutions already provided?

Comment: Honestly, you caught me there.. I thought it worked for me but I haven't been able to follow their instructions due to my poor developing skills. I've been scouring the coder's web and these two developers (rpendleton and kikobeats) are the only ones that seem to grasp the situation and have created a bundle that solves the issue according to peer review on kikobeats website.  (I invite anyone with better skills to verify if their work is good)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work

Answer (score 0):

No need to change libraries or programs or download tools. Everything you need is on hand and easy to use. The tip from 2007 still works: set with "Automator" what you want to do and asign it to a keyboard-shortcut.

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/can-i-assign-f8-the-play-pause-key-to-launch-spotify-instead-of-itunes.1626645/#post-17779801

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it's worth mentioning that this is just adding a new shortcut, and that shortcut can't be the Play/Pause key, so it doesn't quite answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard buttons do not control iTunes (installed with Retroactive) in Catalina. They control the Music app instead.

Answer (score -1):

there is an option on the keyboard to either use the traditional F1, F2, etc keys, or the special features. Maybe you have selected the traditional mode.

Answer (score -1):

Something that works most of the time for me is simply rebooting the program in question.

Say for instance Spotify is not playing nice with the media keys (i.e. they don't do anything when you have Spotify open). I usually quit Spotify and restart it and when it reopens the media keys automatically work again.

Obviously, this is less than ideal and definitely doesn't do anything to make Spotify the 'default' media key program, but it does act as a soft reset for the keys which can help until a better answer is created by Apple / Spotify.

Answer (score -1):

Posting this April 3rd, 2020. Working perfectly well for me.

---

I am using [`shpotify`](https://github.com/hnarayanan/shpotify) with [`skhd`](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd). To install `shpotify` (command line interface for Spotify):

```
brew install shpotify
```

No need to worry about Spotify API if prompted - that is optional if you want to be able to choose tracks from the command line; play/pause, and volume settings work out of the box. Then installing `skhd` (amazing shortcut manager for OSX):

```
brew install koekeishiya/formulae/skhd
brew services start skhd
```

Then head over to the file `~/.skhdrc` which is the configuration file for `skhd` and add the following:

```
# Spotify
fn - f8 : spotify pause
fn - f11 : spotify vol down
fn - f12 : spotify vol up
```

This will map your <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Play/Pause</kbd>, <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Volume Up</kbd>, and <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Volume Down</kbd> to Spotify *specifically*. Pressing any of those keys while Spotify is closed will automatically open it.

The added benefit of using this method is that you can control Spotify when it's playing both on your computer or an external device (i.e. Google Home), and allows more flexibility when pausing Spotify (i.e. when you open a video on the browser and OSX automatically maps the Play/Pause to the video as opposed to music playing in the background by Spotify).