# Disable shortcut (F8) to open Music app?

Tags: catalina, music, shortcut

Is there any way to disable the shortcut for F8 (play/pause key) to open the default Music app?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58234/override-itunes-media-keys-play-pause-etc-for-spotify/249075