# Change default behaviour of play/pause button

Tags: macos, itunes, keyboard, mediaplayer

On my Macbook, if I press the play/pause button (F8) with no other context, MacOS (Mojave) seems to default to opening up iTunes, and playing a particular track. (Maybe the first alphabetically in my entire collection, not sure). I really don't like this particular track :)

Is there anyway I could change this behaviour? For instance, opening Spotify and playing a certain playlist there?

(It's the newer generation bluetooth Apple keyboard, if that matters.)

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58234/399887) is a old post but the software recommend [Beardedspice](http://beardedspice.github.io/) works fine on my Mac. Please read the [full answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356467/399887) because it provides much more detail.